# When I open IE it keeps reverting to an extremely small view

Tags: internet-explorer

If you hold down the control key and scroll the mouse wheel down until the webpage won't get any smaller, that's how IE keeps looking when I open it. I will make it larger and close and reopen it and it will be fine at first, but then later I open it and it has reverted to the small view. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Which version of IE and on which version of Windows?  When you open it, and it's tiny, what Zoom level does IE report it's at?

Answer (score 1):

A hard code solution is not the best option, but should fix you issue quickly via a change in the registry.

> To permanently set the zoom level at 100% , follow these steps:
>
> Click Start, type regedit in the search box, and then click regedit in
>   the Programs list.
>
> Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USERS\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom
> ```
>
> - In the details pane, double-click ZoomFactor.
>
> [image: regeditor view]
>
> - Click Decimal.
> - If you want to set the default zoom level to 100%, type 100000, and    then click OK.
> - Close the Registry Editor.
> - Log off of Windows and then log on again.
>
> Open Internet Explorer. The zoom level should now be set to 100%.

Source [How to set the zoom level in Internet Explorer 9](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2689447)

Comment: Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2689447 (with a very small modification). You're using someone's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on [SU]. Remember to always add prominent attribution and appropriate block quoting when using other sources. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Comment: I've fixed it for you this time. Please take note for next time.